# How to remove last n characters of a filename in R to create a variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have files in a folder titled in this format `Alabama_8422.csv`. My goal is to create a variable state that uses the state specified in the file name.

I saw some posts on how to do this in other softwares, but haven't finagled a way in R yet.

Here is my attempt:

```
data<-read_csv("Alabama_8422.csv")
data<-mutate(data, state=(data[-9]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` to remove `n` characters, or a regex to remove a pattern.

```r
s <- "Alabama_8422.csv"

### if it's always the last 9 characters you want to remove
substring(s, 1, nchar(s) - 9)
# [1] "Alabama"

### remove the last dot and everything after it
gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", s)
# [1] "Alabama_8422"
tools:::file_path_sans_ext(s)
# [1] "Alabama_8422"

### remove everything after the first underscore
gsub("_[^_]*$", "", s)
# [1] "Alabama"

### keep just the first group of letters (case-insens)
### (the space is for New Jersey, etc, not sure if that's how it'll appear)
gsub("^([A-Za-z ]+).*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "Alabama"

### alternative, remove from the optional non-letter character before the first number
gsub("[^A-Za-z]?[0-9].*", "", s)
# [1] "Alabama"
```

@nurandi, thank you for suggesting that I should put this in the context of OP's use of `dplyr`:

```r
mutate(data, state = gsub("^([A-Za-z ]+).*", "\\1", filename))
```

(or whichever `substr`/`gsub` variant you choose).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! When I run the first variant you suggested, I run into this error: ```Error in gsub(substring(s, 1, nchar(s) - 9), data) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default```.

Comment: I never suggested using both `gsub` and `substring` together. Each of the lines above in my code are self-sufficient, all with the intent of removing (via different methods) various components of the string stored in `s`.

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks for walking me through that